# jQuery $.post not executing, how to fix

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am working on a Plugin for WordPress and am having issues with the js code below executing the `$.post`.

The js is called, form validation takes place, the form inputs are serialized into post data correctly, the `$.post` just doesn't execute.

The form is being posted from the Admin, currently I can't get the .submit action to work so am using .click to execute the js function. This may be related to the issue, I am not sure... The form will load without submitting if I use the .submit action, versus using the .click action... never had this issue before and it is pretty frustrating to say the least.

**Here is the code:**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#edit_member_submit").click( function() {

        // define

        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;

        var referrer_id = $("#referrer_id").val();

        // Validate fields START

        if( !referrer_id.match(numbers) ) {

            alert("Please enter a numeric value");

            return false;           

        }

        // Validate fields END       

        $("#ajax-loading-edit-member").css("visibility", "visible");

        // Convert to name value pairs          
        // Define a data object to send to our PHP      

            $.fn.serializeObject = function() {

                var arrayData, objectData;
                arrayData = this.serializeArray();
                objectData = {};

                $.each(arrayData, function() {
                    var value;

                if (this.value != null) {

                  value = this.value;

                } else {

                  value = '';

                }

                if (objectData[this.name] != null) {

                    if (!objectData[this.name].push) {

                    objectData[this.name] = [objectData[this.name]];

                    }

                    objectData[this.name].push(value);

                    } else {

                    objectData[this.name] = value;

                    }

                });

              return objectData;                    

            };          

        var data = $("#edit_member_form").serializeObject(); //the dynamic form elements.

        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));        

        data.action = "edit_member_info"; //the action to call
        data._ajax_nonce = custajaxobj.nonce; // This is the name of the nonce setup in the localize_script

        // Define the URL for the AJAX to call
        var url = custajaxobj.ajaxurl; 

        //alert( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        //alert( JSON.stringify( url ) );

        $.post(url, data, function(response) {

            $("#ajax-loading-edit-member").css("visibility", "hidden");

            alert(response);

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Seems like the last section is having issues:

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) {

        $("#ajax-loading-edit-member").css("visibility", "hidden");

        alert(response);

    });
```

Comment: you missed return at the end of submit handler

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? I am new to js, obviously...

Comment: OK, perfect added 'return false;' and all is well... except still cannot call the function using submit, only when using click handler. Not that I mind as the form updates correctly using .click, but it would be nice to figure out why this isn't working....

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
```

$("#ajax-loading-edit-member").css("visibility", "hidden");

```
    alert(data);
```

});